# Oracle Apex Web Service Soap connection to Salesforce - Numeric or Value Error

Tags: oracle, soap, salesforce, oracle-apex

Running into an annoying problem when querying data from Salesforce via apex_web_service.make_request().

This is coded in oracle PL/SQL and is working fine in general, however it appears that there is some limit on the response size or the XMLTYPE.

In the SOAP envelope that you build I can set the batch size for the number of records to fetch from Salesforce each time (before using a queryMore envelope).

If I leave the value as default (500) or set it to that number manually then the code fails, with Oracle  giving the following error:

ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1472
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", line 168
ORA-06512: at "LIVE.SALESFORCE_PUSH", line 2418
ORA-06512: at "LIVE.SALESFORCE_PUSH", line 95
ORA-06512: at line 4
29273. 00000 -  "HTTP request failed"
*Cause:    The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
*Action:   Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.
           Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.

If I set the batch size to 200, then the error does not occur, which leads me to believe that it is the size of the response that is an issue.

In this example, I have the above workaround, however I have another requirement to pull out large text fields from Salesforce, wherein no matter what batch size I use it fails (the minimum batch size is 200).

Does anyone have any knowledge of the apex_web_service.make_request() procedure or of the XMLTYPE in regards to limits? The error message is fairly cryptic and I can't see another solution currently. I'm beginning to think I may need to expose the data from Salesforce via REST and go about it that route.

Appreciate any help that can be offered.

Thank you

Comment: I've done some further investigating and I'm not actually sure this is a length issue. In a separate example I have added an additional field to the query and this appears to the cause the same error. The error always occurs around the 3000th record to be queried, no matter if done in batched of 1000 or batches of 500.

Comment: So it is a length issue, the question is: what length? There has to be some data structure which cannot hold more than 3000 records. First priority is to find the location of that restriction.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it is a length issue, that is just my assumption based on the errors I am receiving. The code that fails is as follows:
l_xml_query := apex_web_service.make_request(
   p_url => 'http://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/30.0',
   p_action => 'http://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/30.0/query',
   p_envelope => l_envelope_query
  );

l_xml_query is of type XMLTYPE, which the only limit I can find online is 4gb?

Line 168 of APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API" from the stack trace is either the function parse_response or parse_response_clob (the line no is between)

Comment: Apologies, Line 168 of APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API" from the stack trace is obfuscated so I'm not sure what it is.